# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL - PHP and Javascript Zend Studio

Tags: php, jquery, macos, zend-framework, zend-studio

Whenever I open, edit and upload a file from Zend Studio, I get this error when I visit the page. This doesn't occur before uploading. I'm having to delete the file, copy the content and re-upload every time I want to change a file.

The console window in Chrome outputs:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

With these strange red dots?
[image]

How can I stop this from occurring?

I'm using **Zend Studio 10.6** on **Macbook Retina** with **Mavericks 10.9.2**.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with Notepad++ in encoding: `UTF-8 without BOM`. Then look at around your code, maybe there is a illegal character there.

If the solution above does not work, try converting it to encoding: `UTF-8` then continue converting it to `Cp1252` (using Zend Studio IDE).